# Exception trying to run test node

Tags: cardano-node, testnet

I am trying to run a node for testing. I have been through the installation and downloaded the config files from iohk but I am getting an exception when the configs are parsed:

```
AesonException "Error in $: parsing PartialNodeConfiguration failed, expected Object, but encountered String"

cardano-node: Aeson exception:
Error in $: parsing PartialNodeConfiguration failed, expected Object, but encountered String
```

The command I am using is:

```
cardano-node run \
--config /home/mark/cardano_configs/testnet/testnet-config.json \
--database-path /home/mark/cardano_configs/testnet/db/ \
--socket-path /home/mark/cardano_configs/testnet/db/node.socket \
--host-addr 127.0.0.1 \
--port 1337 \
--topology /home/mark/cardano_configs/testnet/testnet-topology.json
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: The links to the json files in the tutorial are out of date.  If you open them they contain url to the new location.  I downloaded them with curl so didnt notice.

Comment: Please update the question with the link you had used.